# Simple about jquery source,confusing about "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I felt very confused about "this" keyword in jquery 1.7.3 source.some snippets showing below:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
constructor: jQuery,
init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
    var match, elem, ret, doc;

    // Handle $(""), $(null), or $(undefined)
    if ( !selector ) {
        return this;   
    }

    // Handle $(DOMElement)
    if ( selector.nodeType ) {
        this.context = this[0] = selector;
        this.length = 1;
        return this;
    }
```

---

```
if ( !selector ) {

  return this;   //why not only one "return" here?
                 //And does "this" refer to jQuery object?
                 //OTOH, this question is about why it returns "this".
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return this allow for chainable plugin call,

```
$(whatever).plugin1().plugin2() etc
```

if you don't `return this` in a plugin you won't be able to chain it
& chaining is fast, & chaining is cool
you want to chain as much as possible in your jquery code

to answer your comment : no you do (**inside plugin definition**):

```
if ($("#div1").get(0)) {
   //do whatever to $("#div1")
   }
return this;
```

`return this` comes **at the end of plugin definition** no need to return it upon any condition whatsoever

Comment: If I don't use jquery in my project,I want to check if an element have an ID call "div1",I general write like this:`if(!document.getElementById('div1')) return;`.in this case,should I write `if(!document.getElementById('div1')) return this` ?

Comment: no return this actually comes at the end of plugin definition whatever happens before; in your example in fact return this should come only once - see answer edit

Answer (score 1):

yes, **this** is jquery object and return **this** make your function chainable.

```
// chaining
$("#person").slideDown('slow')
   .addClass('grouped')
   .css('margin-left', '11px');

// no chaining
$('#person').slideDown('slow');
$('#person').addClass('grouped');
$('#person').css('margin-left', '11px');
```

You see, chaining method help us write code faster and prettier.

In case you want to research further: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining